# How to turn the quarterly data returned by quantmod's viewfin function into a monthly time series?

Tags: r, finance, time-series, quantmod, yahoo-finance

...either spline- (best) or linear-interpolated (OK) or just repeated values (fine) throughout the quarter.  The issue is that I do not know how to convert the data type returned by `getFin()` and `viewFin()` into something `timeSeries`-type usable.  Here is my code:

```
getFin('F')
x <- viewFin(F.f, "BS", period="Q")["Total Common Shares Outstanding",]*1000
```

My desired output is

```
> x
GMT     x.ts
2011-09-01  3816000
2011-08-01  3816000
2011-07-01  3816000
2011-06-01  3815000
2011-05-01  3815000
2011-04-01  3815000
2011-03-01  3813000
2011-02-01  3813000
2011-01-01  3813000
2010-12-01  3778000
2010-11-01  3778000
2010-10-01  3778000
2010-09-01  3484000
```

However, here is some actual output:

```
> x
2011-09-30 2011-06-30 2011-03-31 2010-12-31 2010-09-30 
   3816000    3815000    3813000    3778000    3484000 
> str(x)
 Named num [1:5] 3816000 3815000 3813000 3778000 3484000
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "2011-09-30" "2011-06-30" "2011-03-31" "2010-12-31" ...
```

It looks like the x object is in some strange reverse format, where the key is the numeric value, and the value is a character string of the date.  When I try to extract dates, or the numeric component, I cannot isolate the numeric portion to generate a time series object.

Ideally, to get to my desired output, I would be able to say

```
mydates <- timeSequence(from = "2011-01-01", to=Sys.Date(), by = "month")
series <- timeSeries(x$data, mydates)
```

But I can't seem to extract the numeric data portion.

***UPDATE***

From [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-finance/2009q3/004677.html) and [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/disaggregate-from-monthly-to-daily-time-series-td930098.html), I adapted the following code:

```
getFin('F')
x <- viewFin(F.f, "BS", period="Q")["Total Common Shares Outstanding",]*1000
zoox = zoo(x, order.by=as.Date(names(x)))
x2 <- na.spline(merge(zoox, foo=zoo(NA, order.by=seq(start(zoox), end(zoox), "month")))[, 1])
```

However, my output mangles the dates a bit and messes up the interpolation:

```
>x2
2010-09-30 2010-10-30 2010-11-30 2010-12-30 2010-12-31 2011-01-30 2011-03-02 
   3484000    3623591    3720509    3776671    3778000    3804738    3813071 
2011-03-30 2011-03-31 2011-04-30 2011-05-30 2011-06-30 2011-07-30 2011-08-30 
   3813025    3813000    3813100    3814116    3815000    3814976    3814884 
2011-09-30 
   3816000
```

As you can see, I have both 12-30 and 12-31, 3 values for March-2011, but no February, etc.    How to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, can you please post your answer as an answer instead of adding it to the question?  This will help future visitors to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***UPDATE 2***:

Please post a better answer!  This is really ugly, but here's how I got something acceptable:

```
getFin('F')
x <- viewFin(F.f, "BS", period="Q")["Total Common Shares Outstanding",]*1000
zoox = zoo(x, order.by=as.Date(names(x)))
foo=zoo(NA, order.by=seq(as.Date(as.character(timeFirstDayInMonth(start(zoox)))), as.Date(as.character(timeFirstDayInMonth(end(zoox)))), "month"))
foo2 <- na.approx(merge(zoox, foo)[, 1])
fx <- merge(foo2,foo, all=FALSE)[,1]
```

Which converts

```
> x
2011-09-30 2011-06-30 2011-03-31 2010-12-31 2010-09-30 
   3816000    3815000    3813000    3778000    3484000
```

into

```
> fx
2010-10-01 2010-11-01 2010-12-01 2011-01-01 2011-02-01 2011-03-01 2011-04-01 
   3487196    3586261    3682130    3778389    3790444    3801333    3813022 
2011-05-01 2011-06-01 2011-07-01 2011-08-01 2011-09-01 
   3813681    3814363    3815011    3815348    3815685
```

I find this too ugly to be true, so I post this answer, but want someone else to post a handsomer one.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same problem -- i wrote two functions to make it happen.

First, you want a date function to move dates about, as you probably want month end dates but R deals with first-of dates much more simply.

## Date Functions

```
toLastDay <- function(dateObj, monAdv=0, ToFirst = FALSE)
# takes date object, transforms and returns a dat object
{
  tt <- as.POSIXlt(dateObj)
  tt$mon <- tt$mon + monAdv # moves the month
  tt$mday <- 1L             # make date the first
  if(ToFirst) {             
      tt <- as.Date(tt)
  } else { 
      tt$mon <- tt$mon + 1L # go to the first of the next month
      tt <- as.Date(tt) - 1L # subtract one day, yielding the last of prior month
  }
  return(tt)
}
```

Now you want a function that take the data and does a linear interp -- i use the na.approx function in `zoo` and `xts`. Here you probably want mid-qtr dates -- most qtrly data is best thought of as mid-qtr in my experience.

```
# make Qtrly monthly -- with obsv in the mid qtr
qtr2Mon <- function(QD) 
{
    fromD <- toLastDay(index(first(QD)), -2L, ToFirst = TRUE)
    toD <- toLastDay(index(last(QD)), ToFirst = TRUE)
    q2m_dates <- toLastDay(seq(fromD, toD, by = 'mon'))
    emptyX <- xts(, q2m_dates)
    QD_adj <- QD
    index(QD_adj) <- toLastDay(index(QD), monAdv = -1L)
    mm <- merge(emptyX, QD_adj)
    mm_filled <- na.approx(mm)
    return(mm_filled)
}
```

First we make a qtrly `xts` object -- think of it as qtrly GDP or some such

```
Sys.setenv(TZ = 'GMT')
require(xts)

qdates <- seq(as.Date("2000-03-01"), as.Date("2013-06-01"), by = "3 mon")
qdates <- toLastDay(qdates)
qdata <- rnorm(length(qdates), mean = 1)
qtr_XTS <- xts(qdata, order.by = qdates)
```

Now we can use the above library functions to convert it to monthly, assuming linear growth etc.

```
mon_fromQtr <- qtr2Mon(qtr_XTS)
```

done!